# How do I correctly include data folders into an APK with Buildozer? FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, android, directory, kivy, buildozer

I have made a relatively simple app with Kivy and the root directory contains an "audio" folder with two subfolders in it, each containing a few .wav files. The app runs fine on my desktop but once deployed onto my Android, logcat gives me a FileNotFoundError in relation to the .wav files.

I have included "wav" as a included extention in **buildozer.spec**:

```
#(list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts. = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,wav
```

I believe I am also including the folders correctly here too:

```
#(list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = audio/guard/*.wav,audio/chisau/*.wav
```

The whole process of deployment goes well, until the app is supposed to run. After the Kivy logo the app closes.

Here is the respective snippet of my logcat:

```
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
03-17 17:49:25.967 15383 15437 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-17 17:49:25.967 15383 15437 I python  :    File "/home/luke/WingChun-Assistant/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 51, in <module>
03-17 17:49:25.968 15383 15437 I python  :  FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
03-17 17:49:25.968 15383 15437 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

And here is my main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
import time, sys, random
from threading import Thread
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
pygame.init()


#################################### Variables and Containers ####################


# minimum cooldown between redirections
cooldown = 2

global session_time
session_time = 0

# change of guard redirections
cog_redirections = {"1": "Tan_sau", "2": "Bong_sau", "3": "Kau_sau", "4": "Low_Garn", "5": "Garn_sau",
                "6": "Kwun_sau", "7": "Lap_sau", "8": "Pak_sau", "9": "Gum_sau", "10": "Biu_sau"}

# chi sau redirections
cs_redirections = {"1": "Tan", "2": "Bong", "3": "Gum", "4": "Garn", "5": "Kwun", "6": "Pak"}

# session redirections
global session_list
session_list = []

global function_stop
function_stop = False



######################################### AUDIO ##################################


# change of guard redirections
tan_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Tan_sau.wav")
bong_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Bong_sau.wav")
kau_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Kau_sau.wav")
low_garn = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Low_Garn.wav")
garn_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Garn_sau.wav")
kwun_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Kwun_sau.wav")
lap_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Lap_sau.wav")
pak_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Pak_sau.wav")
biu_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Biu_sau.wav")
gum_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Gum_sau.wav")

# chi sau redirections
tan = mixer.Sound("audio/chisau/Tan.wav")
bong = mixer.Sound("audio/chisau/Bong.wav")
gum = mixer.Sound("audio/chisau/Gum.wav")
garn = mixer.Sound("audio/chisau/Garn.wav")
kwun = mixer.Sound("audio/chisau/Kwun.wav")
pak = mixer.Sound("audio/chisau/Pak.wav")


cog_dict = {"Tan_sau": tan_sau, "Bong_sau": bong_sau, "Kau_sau": kau_sau, "Low_Garn": low_garn,
            "Garn_sau": garn_sau, "Kwun_sau": kwun_sau, "Lap_sau": lap_sau, "Pak_sau": pak_sau,
            "Gum_sau": gum_sau, "Biu_sau": biu_sau, "Tan": tan, "Bong": bong, "Gum": gum,
            "Garn": garn, "Kwun": kwun, "Pak": pak}


global step
step = 1

################################ Buttons and Layouts ###################################

class Widgets(Widget):
    pass

class MainMenu(Screen): # Main Menu

    def red_notes(self):
        RedirectionsNotes().open()

    def chisau_notes(self):
        ChisauNotes().open()


class CSMenu(Screen): # Chi Sau Menu

    def btn(self):
        show_popup()

    def btnt2(self):
        global session_list
        session_list = []
        show_popupt2()

class COGMenu(Screen): # Change of Guard Menu

    def btn(self):
        show_popup()

    def btnt(self):
        global session_list
        session_list = []
        show_popupt()

class InSessionMenu(Screen): # Further Training Session Menu

    def stop_function(self):
        global function_stop
        function_stop = True


class COGSessionMenu(Screen): # Training Session Menu
    def button_press(self):
        # create the thread to invoke other_func with arguments (2, 5)
        t = Thread(target=self.in_session)
        # set daemon to true so the thread dies when app is closed
        t.daemon = True
        # start the thread
        t.start()

    def progress(self):
        # create the thread to invoke other_func with arguments (2, 5)
        t = Thread(target=self.in_progress)
        # set daemon to true so the thread dies when app is closed
        t.daemon = True
        # start the thread
        t.start()


    def in_progress(self):
        global step
        time.sleep(6)
        while function_stop == False:
            if step == 1:
                Pr1().open()
                time.sleep(1)
                step += 1
            elif step == 2:
                Pr2().open()
                time.sleep(1)
                step += 1
            elif step == 3:
                Pr3().open()
                time.sleep(1)
                step = 1


    def play_tech(self, new_dict):
        technique = (random.choice(session_list))
        print(technique)
        new_dict[technique].play()


    def in_session(self):
        global function_stop
        function_stop = False
        Gr5().open()
        time.sleep(1)
        Gr4().open()
        time.sleep(1)
        Gr3().open()
        time.sleep(1)
        Gr2().open()
        time.sleep(1)
        Gr1().open()
        time.sleep(1)
        Gr().open()
        now = time.time()
        timer = 0
        while timer < session_length and function_stop == False:
            self.play_tech(cog_dict)
            end = time.time()
            timer = round(end - now)
            print(timer)
            time.sleep((cooldown + random.randint(0, 4)))
        return


    def stop_function(self):
        global function_stop
        function_stop = True

class DiffMenu(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

################## Popups #########################

################## Progress Popups #################

class Pr1(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Pr1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()

class Pr2(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Pr2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()

class Pr3(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Pr3, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()

################## Notes Popups ######################

class RedirectionsNotes(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RedirectionsNotes, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self.dismiss()

class ChisauNotes(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChisauNotes, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self.dismiss()
################ Get Ready Popups ############

class Gr5(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Gr5, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()
class Gr4(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Gr4, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()
class Gr3(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Gr3, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()
class Gr2(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Gr2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()
class Gr1(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Gr1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()
class Gr(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Gr, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.dismiss_popup, 1)

    def dismiss_popup(self, dt):
        self.dismiss()

################ Session Length Menu ###############
class P(FloatLayout):

    def session_time_60(self):
        global session_length
        session_length = 60
        print(session_length)

    def session_time_120(self):
        global session_length
        session_length = 120
        print(session_length)

    def session_time_300(self):
        global session_length
        session_length = 300
        print(session_length)

    def session_time_600(self):
        global session_length
        session_length = 600
        print(session_length)


################ Change of Guard Techniques Menu ##########
class Pt(FloatLayout):
    def populate_pt(self, technique):
        if technique in session_list:
            session_list.remove(technique)
            print(session_list)
        else:
            session_list.append(technique)
            print(session_list)




################ Chi Sau Techniques Menu #################
class Pt2(FloatLayout):
    def populate_pt2(self, technique):
        if technique in session_list:
            session_list.remove(technique)
            print(session_list)
        else:
            session_list.append(technique)
            print(session_list)



class Wing_Chun_Training_AssistantApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv



##################################### Functions #############################################



def show_popup():
    show = P()

    popupWindow = Popup(background_color = [1, 0.0, 0.0, 1], separator_color =  [0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 1], title = "Choose Length of Session, then click outside to close", content = show, size_hint = (0.8, 0.8), size = (400, 400))


    popupWindow.open()


def show_popupt():
    showt = Pt()

    popupWindowt = Popup(background_color = [1, 0.0, 0.0, 1], separator_color =  [0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 1], title = "Select Techniques to Train, then click outside to close", content = showt, size_hint = (0.8, 0.8), size = (400, 400))

    popupWindowt.open()


def show_popupt2():
    showt2 = Pt2()

    popupWindowt2 = Popup(background_color = [1, 0.0, 0.0, 1], separator_color =  [0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 1], title = "Select Techniques to Train, then click outside to close", content = showt2, size_hint = (0.8, 0.8), size = (400, 300))

    popupWindowt2.open()



###################################### Run Loop ##############################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Wing_Chun_Training_AssistantApp().run()
```

The line  `tan_sau = mixer.Sound("audio/guard/Tan_sau.wav")`, is line 51

In addition to this, my root folder contains my main.py file, .kv file, a background .png file and an audio folder. The audio folder contains two said subfolders with the wav files in them.

I have extracted the contents of the APK file and there's no sign of the wavs anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for any help given.

Edit:

The audio folder along with the two sub folders and the wav files are indeed in the apk file. I am still however getting the same error.

Comment: What folders are present on the device? Are any of the files present? Also, why does your logcat mention pygame?

Comment: Do you mean what folders are present within the .APK?

Comment: I use pygame's mixer to play sounds as I was having issues with kivy's sound module.

Comment: Within the .APK file there are 4 folders: assets, lib, META-INF and res. Neither contains the wavs.

Comment: Those folders would not be expected to contain the wavs. Use the logcat output to print debug information about what folders are present when the apk is unzipped.

Comment: Or look in the private.mp3 file in the apk (it's a tarball)

Comment: Upon inspection of the private.mp3 file, I can confirm the folders and files are all there. Where have I gone wrong then?

Comment: What happens if you open the file via another method, e.g. `open("path")`?

Comment: Which file? private.mp3? I accessed it via sudo su

Comment: The file in your apk that you cannot load with mixer.Sound

Comment: The real point here is, you want to debug exactly what's wrong - all you have to start with is a message saying "FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.", so the first step is to verify if that means what it looks like it means. In this case, you've found that the file apparently _should_ exist, so maybe something else is wrong. I would try loading the file from python (`open("audio/guard/Tan_sau.wav")`) and see if that works. If it does, you've isolated the problem to the pygame function call. If it doesn't, you can further inspect the file  to get more information.

Comment: Yup, the file opens fine in python just fine and the sound plays as intended in python and in a windows package made via py installer. Perhaps buildozer is not a fan of pygame at all. I am at a loss here.

Comment: Another option would be to move all the wav files to the root directory along with the main.py and the .kv file, change the paths within the python code and see if that works. But that would make for a very messy and busy root folder.

Comment: This is now solved. Thank you sincerely for your time.

Comment: When I said try loading the file from python, I meant on the device. It doesn't matter that it works on your local computer, because that isn't where the file not found error was.

Comment: Oh I see. My apologies. That actually makes much more sense. I bit more than I could chew with this project. Now that it's done, back to polishing basics. Thank you again for all your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try playing audio files using Kivy's own SoundLoader function. Like this:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

sound = SoundLoader.load('mytest.wav')
if sound:
    print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
    print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    sound.play()
```

More information can be found [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html).

Also, try to use `os.path.join` as [@NameKhan72](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12909098/namekhan72) has mentioned in his answer. Don't forget to `import os` first. Clean up the Buildozer folder (in your project folder) before rebuilding apk again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have gone back to kivy SoundLoader and it works like a dream, with my standard paths. On top of that, very curiously, the problem I had with it before ( the sound were cutting out short ), which was the reason I chose pygame, has fixed itself after deploying to android. I will keep the Windows version with the pygame's mixer and use kivy's SoundLoader for the android release. Again, Many thanks for taking interest and time helping me with this.

Comment: I've gone through such type of problems with Kivy and learned basic Android development with Java. I hope one day we will be able to create Android apps with Python (Kivy or other framework) hassle free.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind my original answer. I noticed too late, that I was wrong.

I did some research and apparently Buildozer can resort to cached versions of the build and not rebuild the project before compiling. Try deleting the hidden buildozer folder and rebuild the project.

EDIT 1:

Try using the absolute path of the file with this method:

```
root_folder = self.user_data_dir  # only works in the App class, so make it a global variable
```

Then you could do:

```
tan_sau_path = os.path.join(root_folder, 'audio/guard/Tan_sau.wav')
tan_sau = mixer.Sound(tan_sau_path)
```

from the class you plan to use the sound from.

Comment: Just tried that. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. Could it be something to do with build_dir or bin_dir in buildozer.spec?

Comment: Hard to say... Do you have definitive proof that the files have not been included? I'd suggest listing everything using listdir and printing the output in the Logcat.

Comment: The files are indeed there. As requested by someone else commenting, I have looked into the private.mp3 file and the folders and files are there. I'm very new to Linux and I'm not sure how to use listdir with logcat. I'm sorry if I'm not helping you help me.

Comment: No worries! Treat logcat as your regular python console. Everything python would usually output there (ie. Print(), etc.) goes to the logcat. If you are sure, that the files are indeed there, Id look into the path. What strikes me as odd, is that the path in the error message you provided doesn't look like an "android-path" in the slightest. To me it looks like it originates from your linux machine. See the edit for a possible fix.

Comment: I have just changed my build so that all the wav files are located in the root folder and in python, I changed the paths to root folder paths and I'm still getting the same error. This makes me think it's not a path issue. I will now update my question to feature my full main.py file. Maybe you can spot something which would disagree with buildozer and android, as as I said, the app works perfectly fine when deployed to windows via PyInstaller. By the way thank you so much for taking your time trying to help me.

Comment: A complete build log + logcat would probably help a lot. Could you maybe do that? Just output the console to a file like so: buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt

Then you could output the file or send it to me via Discord (NameKhan72#5729 if you have it)

I also just noticed what WingChun is. I actually took lessons for a couple of years. Very cool stuff!

Comment: This is now solved. Thank you for taking your time helping me.

Comment: I just noticed your previous comment sorry. Yeah I've been putting a logcat onto a txt file everytime. Been told it's the best way to do things. And yes Wing Chun is awesome :)